# How to get bounce light to work in Eevee already ahve SSGI on

Tags: eevee-render-engine

Anyone know how to get bounce lighting in Eevee to work properly?
I set a basic plane next to a model and in Eevee with SSG turned on theres no bounce
And to confirm it was bouncing I went in cycles and it worked
https://ibb.co/t3GnkRz

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Have you tried Irradiance volume and Bake Indirect Light method? Perhaps this tutorial will help https://youtu.be/9SD0of-mOHo

Comment: @sirrus
Wasnt SSGI supposed to take care of this being the next big thing?

Comment: SSGI, I assume you mean addon? If so, Yes, it could take care of it, I believe this is great addon. Since its not offical Blender's builds, What would you do when developer decide to stop support this addon? What would you do if this addon encounters bugs when upgrade into new Blender version? Its always best to learn vanilla.